# NetBeans IDE 12.5 no Project Open

Tags: java, netbeans, java-8

I'm running NetBeans IDE 12.5 with Java 1.8.0_311 on Mac OS 11.16 Big Sur.
No Folders are displayed in the Projects Window, no difference with new created or old projects.
I already adjusted the netbeans.conf to the right JDK home directory:

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

Also I get an Unexpected Exception - java.lang.NullPointerException in the notifications when trying to open a project.
Full trace:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.metadata.model.api.support.annotation.AnnotationModelHelper.runJavaSourceTaskWhenScanFinished(AnnotationModelHelper.java:190)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.impl.webservices.annotation.WebservicesMetadataModelImpl.runReadActionWhenReady(WebservicesMetadataModelImpl.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.metadata.model.api.MetadataModel.runReadActionWhenReady(MetadataModel.java:160)
    at org.netbeans.modules.websvc.core.jaxws.projects.JavaEEWSOpenHook.projectOpened(JavaEEWSOpenHook.java:80)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:60)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.support.UILookupMergerSupport$OpenHookImpl.projectOpened(UILookupMergerSupport.java:223)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:60)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(OpenProjectList.java:1323)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.access$1600(OpenProjectList.java:116)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$LoadOpenProjects.loadOnBackground(OpenProjectList.java:513)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$LoadOpenProjects.run(OpenProjectList.java:384)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I found a similar question on stack overflow where adjusting the config file was mentioned as a possible solution.

Output from IDE Log:

```
    WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.XMLDataObject@20e83598[MultiFileObject@19d29edf[Actions/Help/master-help.xml]]
WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.options.keymap.LayersBridge]: Invalid shortcut: org.openide.loaders.BrokenDataShadow@72ee9bcd[MultiFileObject@58de53e0[Keymaps/NetBeans/D-BACK_QUOTE.shadow]]
WARNING [null]: Last record repeated again.
```

Any other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Update your question to show all of the following: [1] The stack trace for the exception. [2] Select **View > IDE Log** to display the NetBeans log file in the **Output** window, then update your question to show any relevant messages from that log. [3] The environment information displayed in the **Help > About** window.

Comment: Also, while I'm not familiar with macOS, I know that it used to always include some version of Java (whether you wanted it or not). Is it possible that you are inadvertently referencing an unwanted version of Java? Also, are you using any versions of Java in NetBeans apart from  8u311? Do you even have any versions of Java other than 8u311 installed?

Comment: Thanks  for answering @skomisa! I added some more information in the question. I already tried different Java versions. JDK 17.0.1, JDK1.8.0_201 & JDK1.8.0_311. Error with missing Projects is only with JDK1.8.0_*. I can see the projects with JDK 17 but this is causing some other problems.